# Laravel redirect if a user field is not 1

Tags: php, laravel, redirect

In an layout.app I want to redirect users if a field in the user table is not one. I want to send them to a Members dashboard.

I have tried this in the top of my file

```
if (Auth::user()->admin <> 1)
{
    session()->flash('error','you are not authorised for the administration area');
    return redirect()->action([App\Http\Controllers\MembersController::class,'dashboard']);
}
```

but it does not redirect - I just get the session message.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: The if condition should be `!=` not `<>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer after clarification**

You can't directly redirect from a Blade template.

Either you use JavaScript like this:

```js
window.location.href = "{{ route('Members.dashboard') }}";
```

Or, the way I would recommend, is to place your control logic in the controller that's responsible for your view. From there, you can easily redirect as mentioned earlier. This approach may require some code refactoring, but it could be worth your time, especially if your application grows.

---

**Old Answer**
As far as I understand your question, for the redirect you should just open the route of your dashboard. Assuming the route to the dashboard is `/members/dashboard`:

```
 return redirect('/members/dashboard');
```

Or if you have a named route use:

```
return redirect()->route('members-dashboard');
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried both your suggestion but it does not move to the route or the address.

Comment: Can you provide some more information about how the routes are set up? From what file are you trying to redirect? Is it a controller or a view?

Comment: It's at the top of a view. The route is OK (Members.dashboard) and I add a button with an onlick to go there no trouble. It just seems the recirect does not want to work. I added a dd in the conditional to make sure it was going there which it is.

Comment: the php header("location: whatever") works fine!

Comment: @Jim please mark as solved, if it worked for please

Comment: It is easier to put it in the layout.app so I used the PHP header as I mentioned earlier. It does what I want now. But thanks for the enlightenment about blade  templates now being able to redirect.